# FFmpeg command line not working as expected: Subtitles set as “dvdsub” and audio is not AAC as specified in the command

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, metadata

I want to encode an film but I have some problems:

1. The subtitles are converted to dvdsub. If I play the file in VLC the subtitles getting overlapped. In every other player this not happend (like SMPlayer or Kodi).
2. The 2nd soundtrack is in Vorbis coded and not in ACC. I cant explain me that, because in the command line I explicitly set AAC.
3. How can I define, which track is default and wich not.

My command line to encode:

```
ffmpeg -i 1.mkv -threads 12 -aspect 16:9 -c:v libx265 -tune grain -x265-params crf=23 -filter:v "crop=in_w-0-0:in_h-20-19:0:20" -map 0:v -metadata:s:v:0 language="ger" -metadata:s:v:0 title="xy" -map 0:a:0 -c:a:0 aac -b:a:0 225k -ac:a:0 6 -metadata:s:a:0 language="ger" -metadata:s:a:0 title="Surround 5.1" -map 0:a:2 -c:a:2 aac -b:a:2 225k -ac:a:2 6 -metadata:s:a:2 language="eng" -metadata:s:a:2 title="Surround 5.1" -map 0:s -c:s dvdsub 2.mkv
```

So what is wrong with this command line?

Comment: Your command explicitly has `-c:s dvdsub` near the end. So that is probably where the “dvdsub” is coming from.

Comment: 2. wrong map `... -map 0:a:2 -c:a:1 aac...`

Comment: no wrong map `-map 0:a:2 -c:a:2 aac`

Comment: "So that is probably where the “dvdsub” is coming from." What u mean ? U have to convert subtitles if they are in hdmv_pgs_subtitle to dvdsub

Comment: 2. you did mapping: `-map 0:v -map 0:a:0 -map 0:a:2` that gives you new enumeration of output streams. So, now you have 2 audio streams in output `-c:a:0` and `-c:a:1` etc

Comment: hey Баяр Гончикжапов, ty for answer. Now i know what u mean Ty this problem is solved. Do u have any suggests beacause of the subtitles?

Comment: my mistake. I said wrong map, at real, it is a wrong stream selection. About dvdsub, imho dvdsub is broken in ffmpeg.

Comment: Ty Баяр Гончикжапов for answering, that helped me a lot !!